# set width in jTable doesn't work

Tags: java, jtable

i have a jTable into a jScrollPane, the problem is that when i define the width to a column, but all the columns gets the same width, this is my code

```
public AsistenciasPanel() {
        initComponents();
        jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(jTable1.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTable1);
        jTable1.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
        jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(229, 232, 221));
        setDataTable();

    }


private void setDataTable() {
         String data[][] = QueryManager.getAlumnosByCursoId(idCurso);
         DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable1.getModel();
         model.setRowCount(data.length);
         String asistencias[][] = QueryManager.getAsistencias(idBimestre);
         int columCount = asistencias.length;
         String[] columnNames = {
             "ID",
             "Name"};

         model.setColumnCount(0);
         model.addColumn(columnNames[0]);
         model.addColumn(columnNames[1]);
         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(10);
         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setWidth(50);
         idAsistencias = new int[columCount];
         listaAsistencias = new int[data.length][columCount];
         for (int i = 0; i < columCount; i++) {
             model.addColumn(asistencias[i][2].split(" ")[0]);
             idAsistencias[i] = Integer.parseInt(asistencias[i][0]);
             jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i+2).setWidth(20);
         }
}
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: Use setPreferredWidth instead of setWidth.

Comment: it's the same result

Comment: Where do you add `jScrollPane1` to? Do you use a proper layout manager?

Comment: i use the ui tool,  drag and drop

Comment: Still it seems that the problem lies outside of the code you posted (maybe in `initComponents()`) when using `setPreferredWidth()` doesn't fix it. Try to make your problem reproduceable for others.

Comment: if you don't know the answer please don't comment